# Laravel 5 Mailing Issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-mail

I seem to be having issues when trying to perform password resets with Laravel 5. The error I keep getting is:

```
View [layouts] not found. 
(View: /var/www/leaptrade/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/resources/views/html/message.blade.php) 
(View: /var/www/leaptrade/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/resources/views/html/message.blade.php)
```

I've checked through all of my views and ensured that they all are correct, but I keep getting this error. It occurs after I click "Send Password Reset Link". The path it redirects to is correct, from `/password/reset` to `/password/email`, and it also only causes an error when it's a correct user Email.

Would anybody happen to have any ideas on a solution for this?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the layout that your reset password email template is using?

Comment: Where would this be located exactly? I have recreated the reset functionality for another user type ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNdVW8lsFOo ) and everything looks fine within the controllers. 

I just tested the views to make sure there were no issues on them and it didn't return any errors that shouldn't be there (token not found error; since I just tested via routing instead of being redirected to it with a token as intended)